# jquery and pagination issue

Tags: jquery, pagination

Im using a carousel plug in. Code is

```
// carousel
var Carousel = {
    settings: {
        itemsPerPage: 1,
        itemsPerTransition: 1,
        noOfRows: 1,
        pagination: true,
        nextPrevLinks: true,
        speed: 'normal',
        easing: 'swing'
    },
    init: function(el, options) {
        if (!el.length) {return false;}
        this.options = $.extend({}, this.settings, options);
        this.itemIndex = 0; 
        this.container = el;
        this.runner = this.container.find('ul');
        this.items = this.runner.children('li');
        this.noOfItems = this.items.length;
        this.setRunnerWidth();
        if (this.noOfItems <= this.options.itemsPerPage) {return false;} // bail if there are too few items to paginate
        this.insertMask();
        this.noOfPages = Math.ceil((this.noOfItems - this.options.itemsPerPage) / this.options.itemsPerTransition) + 1;
        if (this.options.pagination) {this.insertPagination();}
        if (this.options.nextPrevLinks) {this.insertNextPrevLinks();}
        this.updateBtnStyles();
    },
    insertMask: function() {
        this.runner.wrap('<div class="mask" />');
        this.mask = this.container.find('div.mask');

        // set mask height so items can be of varying height
        var maskHeight = this.runner.outerHeight(true);
        this.mask = this.container.find('div.mask');
        this.mask.height(maskHeight);
    },
    setRunnerWidth: function() {
        this.noOfItems = Math.round(this.noOfItems / this.options.noOfRows);
        var width =  this.items.outerWidth(true) * this.noOfItems;
        this.runner.width(width);
    },
    insertPagination: function() {
        var i, links = [];
        this.paginationLinks = $('<ol class="pagination-links" />');
        for (i = 0; i < this.noOfPages; i++) {
            links[i] = '<li><a href="#item-' + i + '">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>';
        }
        this.paginationLinks
            .append(links.join(''))
            .appendTo(this.container)
            .find('a')
                .bind('click.carousel', $.proxy(this, 'paginationHandler'));
    },
    paginationHandler: function(e) {
        this.itemIndex = e.target.hash.substr(1).split('-')[1] * this.options.itemsPerTransition;
        this.animate();
        return false;
    },
    insertNextPrevLinks: function() {
        this.prevLink = $('<div id=leftbutton <img src=images/leftbutton.png width=80 height=48></div>')
                            .bind('click.carousel', $.proxy(this, 'prevItem'))
                            .appendTo(this.container);
        this.nextLink = $('<div id=rightbutton <img src=images/rightbutton.png width=80 height=48></div>')
                            .bind('click.carousel', $.proxy(this, 'nextItem'))
                            .appendTo(this.container);
    },
    nextItem: function() {
        this.itemIndex = this.itemIndex + this.options.itemsPerTransition;
        this.animate();
        return false;
    },
    prevItem: function() {
        this.itemIndex = this.itemIndex - this.options.itemsPerTransition;
        this.animate();
        return false;
    },
    updateBtnStyles: function() {
        if (this.options.pagination) {
            this.paginationLinks
                .children('li')
                    .removeClass('current')
                    .eq(Math.ceil(this.itemIndex / this.options.itemsPerTransition))
                        .addClass('current');
        }

        if (this.options.nextPrevLinks) {
            this.nextLink
                .add(this.prevLink)
                    .removeClass('disabled');
            if (this.itemIndex === (this.noOfItems - this.options.itemsPerPage)) {
                this.nextLink.addClass('disabled');
            } 
            else if (this.itemIndex === 0) {
                this.prevLink.addClass('disabled');
            }
        }
    },
    animate: function() {
        var nextItem, pos;
        // check whether there are enough items to animate to
        if (this.itemIndex > (this.noOfItems - this.options.itemsPerPage)) {
            this.itemIndex = this.noOfItems - this.options.itemsPerPage; // go to last panel - items per transition
        }
        if (this.itemIndex < 0) {
            this.itemIndex = 0; // go to first
        }
        nextItem = this.items.eq(this.itemIndex);
        pos = nextItem.position();

        if (headache) {
            this.runner
                .stop()
                .animate({left: -pos.left}, this.options.speed, this.options.easing);
        }
        else {
            this.mask
                .stop()
                .animate({scrollLeft: pos.left}, this.options.speed, this.options.easing);
        }
        this.updateBtnStyles();
    }
};


// bridge
$.fn.carousel = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var obj = Object.create(Carousel);
        obj.init($(this), options);
        $.data(this, 'carousel', obj);
    });
};
```

The problem I'm having is with the pagination. I want to be able to move it to a different DIV. Changing the appendTo breaks the code, I cant specify another div to stick it in.

Any help would be great.